# WebRTC for Android: Crashes on second call

Tags: android, webrtc

I have developed an Android app for video conference using WebRTC. I used the available Java Library for the same.

I can successfully make a P2P call. However, when i make the same P2P call again one-after-another, I get the following error:

```
SetRemoteDescription failed: Called with type in wrong state, type: answer state:    
STATE_INPROGRESS
```

However when I restart the app, I can make the call again, it works flawlessly.

Summary: In order to make a second call, I have to restart the application. It might be because of some possible caching of some objects like PC, SDPObserver or PCObserver. I make all of them null and also kill the activity after the first call. Even then second call doesn't work unless I restart my app.

What can be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the local resources are not properly disposed even though you are killing the activity.

Make sure you are calling when the video call ends:

```
peerConnection.dispose();
videoSource.dispose();
peerConnectionFactory.dispose();
```

You can test that this works on the AppRTCDemo reference app. Here is the reference [code](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/examples/android/src/org/appspot/apprtc/AppRTCDemoActivity.java#562).